# how to see each pixel being changed on the canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, image-processing, canvas

I've created a filter in javascript which inverts the colors of image i.e creates a negative image,  now when I run it in the browser it takes time to process and then returns the final negative image. How can I see each pixel of the image being inverted and not just the final inverted image? Instead of waiting for the the code to be implemented on the whole pixel array and then see its effects, I want to see each pixel being changed by the code till the last pixel.

```
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,x.width,x.height);
var d = imgData.data;
        for (var i=0; i< d.length; i+=4) {
        d[i] = 255 - d[i];
       d[i+1] = 255 - d[i+1];
       d[i+2] = 255 - d[i+2];

        }
ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
```

NEW CODE

```
invert(d,0);
function invert(d,i){
    if(i < d.length){
         d[i] = 255 - d[i];
               d[i+1] = 255 - d[i+1];
               d[i+2] = 255 - d[i+2];
               d[i+3] = d[i+3];
               //alert(i);
               var n=i/4;
            var h=parseInt(n/x.width);

            var w = n - h*x.width;

            ctx.fillStyle='rgba('+d[i]+','+d[i+1]+','+d[i+2]+','+d[i+3]/255+')';

            ctx.fillRect(w,h,1,1);

            //if(i>91000){alert(i);}
          setTimeout(invert(d,i+4),50);
    }
    else{return ;}
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could `context.fillRect` each newly changed pixel on the canvas as it's calculated.

Something like this (*warning: untested code, may need tweeks!*):

```
var n=i/4;
var y=parseInt(n/canvas.width);
var x=n-y*canvas.width;
context.fillStyle='rgba('+d[i]+','+d[i+1]+','+d[i+2]+','+d[i+3]/255')';
context.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
```

Here's demo code that first does the inverting and then shows the effect over time:

```js
        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        var cw=canvas.width;
        var ch=canvas.height;


var nextTime=0;
// a new line of converted image will be displayed
// after this delay
var delay=1000/60*2;
var y=0;

var imgData,d;

var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sun.png";
function start(){

    cw=canvas.width=img.width;
    ch=canvas.height=img.height;
    
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    
    imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch);
    d=imgData.data;
    
    for (var i=0; i< d.length; i+=4) {
        d[i] = 255 - d[i];
        d[i+1] = 255 - d[i+1];
        d[i+2] = 255 - d[i+2];
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function animate(time){

    if(time<nextTime){requestAnimationFrame(animate); return;}
    nextTime=time+delay;
   
    for(var x=0;x<cw;x++){
        var i=(y*cw+x)*4;
        ctx.fillStyle='rgba('+d[i]+','+d[i+1]+','+d[i+2]+','+d[i+3]/255+')';
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
    }

    if(++y<ch){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }else{
        ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
    }

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: it should be var x = n - y*canvas.width, after correcting the logic is correct but still the picture is inverting very quickly so I decided to add a setTimeout after each pixel is updating, and changed the code but that is not working. I'm editing the code again.

Comment: Thanks for the catch on my error--I was in a hurry this morning! I've posted a demo that first fully inverts the `imageData.data` and then uses those converted pixels to do a slowed down reveal to the viewer. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an asynchronous "loop" so you can update some pixels, let the display update the result, then continue.

JavaScript is single threaded so nothing will be updated until the current loop finishes as the thread is occupied with that.

## Watching the paint dry

Here is one approach you can use. You define a "batch" size in number of pixels you want to invert (1 is valid if you want to see each pixel, but this can take a long time:

```
ie. 16.67ms x total number of pixels.
```

So if you want to display each single pixel update with an image of 640x400 (as in the demo below) then it would take:

```
640 x 400 x 16.67ms = 4,267,520 ms, or more than an hour
```

Something to have in mind (the display cannot update faster than per 16.67ms = 60 fps). Below we use 128 pixels per batch.

## Live example

Note that the batch value must match the width of the image. F.ex. if your image is 640 pixels wide you can use 1, 5, 10, 20, .. 64, 128 etc.

If you want widths that do not necessarily divide on anything but 1 or fractional values, you have to do a simple calculation to limit the last batch of one line as `getImageData()` require the arguments to define the area inside an image. Or, just do line by line...

You can also use a "batch" value for vertical tiles (box is probably a better term in that case).

```js
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "";
img.onload = painter;
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/Hl3I0cx.jpg";

function painter() {

  // setup canvas and image
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  // set canvas size = image size
  canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;

  // draw in image
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  
  // prepare loop
  var batch = 128,
      x = 0, y = 0,
      w = canvas.width - batch,
      h = canvas.height;
  
  (function asyncUpdate() {
  
    // do one batch only
    var idata = ctx.getImageData(x, y, batch, 1),  // get a bacth of pixels
        data = idata.data,
        i = 0, len = data.length;
    
    while(i < len) {                               // invert the batch
      data[i] = 255 - data[i++];
      data[i] = 255 - data[i++];
      data[i] = 255 - data[i++];
      i++
    }
    
    ctx.putImageData(idata, x, y);                 // update bitmap
    
    x += batch;
    if (x > w) {                                   // check x pos
      x = 0;
      y++;
    }
    
    if (y < h) {                                  // new batch?
      requestAnimationFrame(asyncUpdate);         // let display update before next
    }
    else {
      // use a callback here...
      console.log("Done");
    }
  })();
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: The solution is great but Can it be done without using animation? I mean the fillRect(x,y,1,1) method puts each pixel in its position one by one and if we add a delay then we could actually see each pixel being put?? I tried to do that and I've added a new code but there seems to be some problem.